# ColdFusion 10 -I have one Scheduled Task that is not working but many others work fine. We do have SSL cert

Tags: ssl, scheduled-task, coldfusion

I see several questions similar to my problem.  They mention ColdFusion and Scheduled Tasks not working.  I use ColdFusion 10 with SSL certificate.  But I have only one Scheduled Task that is not working.  When using the URL and running it from the page, they all work fine.  But I can't Run this one from CF Administrator Scheduled Tasks. I have many others that work fine.  I have tried the CFLog and nothing gets posted to my log files.  It's like it doesn't call the page at all but I do get the alert at the top of the page saying "This scheduled task was completed successfully." but nothing happens.  Nothing in the log files and the data updates are not done.

The page is very simple and takes less than a minute to run (from the page) so it's not a timeout problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Found we were in a folder requiring login (with the application.cfm) instead of our schedulers folder used to just run the page without login.  Moved the scheduled task page to this folder and was able to run the page cf administrator.  Just hope this helps someone else.  We were quite baffled there for a while.

Comment: you can actually add your comment as an accepted answer after a period of time, in case someone else runs in to the same issue in the future